# Exclaimation mark at end of url what does it do?

Tags: html, apache

I want help understanding as to what the (!) mark means when put infront of an URL like

http://192.168.1.44/!

When i enter the url on the browser it display the directories. Right on the top first is a file which is named (!). When i open the link there is a php script which is basically connecting to mysql using the username and password supplied in the script. Then in rest of lines there are some sql statement which is no major coding just some kind of script to display list of employee with their pictures from erp database.

I see a point in script code but i don't see why its put as (!) and what does it actually do? Can someone please tell me its programing significance and otherwise please.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing inherently special about the `!` character in URLs. It is often used by various web frameworks to denote "dynamic pages", or a page that is generated mostly with AJAX requests.

I believe google will index pages ending in !# as normal pages to allow for this, but other than that, it has no special meaning other that what a programmer has given it.

Comment: Thanks i just was paying too much attention. Thanks for commenting